# Why does F3 return nothing searching for dyntopo?

Tags: documentation

I'm looking for the checkbox `dyntopo` (2.91). F3 returns nothing. How can I find it without asking here or searching the web?

Comment: Wait, are you just looking to find it from the search menu, or is the actual option missing in the sculpting tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Dyntopo* isn't displayed in the *F3 Menu Search*, since it's not a menu item.
However, you can find it through the *Operator search*.

1. Switch to Sculpt Mode
2. Check *Developer Extras* in *Preferences > Interface* (to enable Operator search)
3. Go *Edit > Operator Search > Dynamic Topology Toggle*

[image]

Comment: I asked the question after the documentation failed to help me. I should rephrase the question: How to search in blender for the `Sidebar > Tool > Dyntopo` or any other `Panel: x > y > z`

Comment: Oh, right, I'll update the answer :).

Comment: Is there maybe a 3rd party plugin which provides a search result similar to your circling cursor? (thank you for that). In short: A search result similar to your gif to show me **where to look**

Comment: No idea, never seen such functionality in any software :).